# What is the use of the Visible property in the case of a HiddenField?

Tags: asp.net, oop, properties, controls, hidden-field

The `Visible` property, as I understand it, helps to enable or disable the visibility of a control.

But what is its use in the case of the `HiddenField` control in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7):

The `Visible` property on a HiddenField functions like it does on other controls.   If a HiddenField control has its `Visible` property set to `false`, the control is **not rendered to the page**.  Normally HiddenField is rendered as an `<input type= "hidden"/>` element.   But if it is not Visible, its data is held in the page's viewstate instead.

The reason the HiddenField was introduced in .Net 2.0 was as an alternative to

- view state
- session state
- cookies

as places to store that sort of hidden state information when those locations are either unavailable or undesirable.   Setting Visible to false just forces it to use viewstate again instead of rendering the `<input type= "hidden"/>`.  So it defeats the purpose a little, but it is a well-understood container for a bit of data the user doesn't need to see.

Whether or not it is rendered as an element in the document (Visible = true) or viewstate encoded (Visible = false), doesn't make that much of a difference.

It is important to know that a HiddenField's value is in-fact sent with the page even when the visible property is false, and should not be used for sensitive information.

[ASP.NET HiddenField Visible Property](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/HiddenField-Control-in-ASP-Net.aspx)

[ASP.NET HiddenField on wiki.ASP.NET](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/298/hiddenfield/)

Answer (score 5):

**The `Visible` property is present even on a `HiddenField` object because of *[inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)*.**

The documentation indicates that the [`HiddenField` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) inherits from the base [`Control` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx), which defines the `Visible` property. Inheritance means that all classes who inherit from a base class automatically gain, or pick up, all of the methods exposed by the base class. In this case, `HiddenField` is picking up the `Visible` property of its base `Control` class, even despite it's apparent uselessness that you point out in the question.

It's not because languages often have "silly things" (although I won't dispute the veracity of that claim), it's because an object-oriented design makes it impossible to remove methods from derived classes that are inherited from base classes.

Answer (score -4):

Probably because it was harder to make it not be there than to leave it there.

Many languages have silly things. Like the Unary + operator in C and C++

Comment: Clearly, the purpose of the unary `+` operator in C/C++ is to serve as the opposite of the unary `-` operator! :-) (not my downvote)

Comment: @ Enabren No I don't think that it is put there because they cant leave it. @cody:  If the property is there it must be having some meaning that is to search because if we do inherit something accidently it does not mean it does not help us to do the same as the parent class do. So I think operation for this is still to find out